# Compiling ffmpeg for android on windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I tried more than 5 open source library, I have no success to build them on windows.

This is my first time using NDK and wondering why I can't simply find the .so file and use it instead of compiling from scratch.

Please guide me with your knowledge, I am kind of stuck here.
thank you

Comment: What functionality do you require from ffmpeg ?

Comment: grabbing frames from video, and creating video from list of images. and maybe overlay 2 images to one if ffmpeg has a method to do that.

Comment: Ah, ok .. so you need a complete ffmpeg and java interface. Did you try  https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg ?

Comment: I believe so. I wasted my 2-3 days to compile but no success :/

Comment: Actually, I only managed to get the appunite ffmpeg library compiled after quite a bit of effort but that was on linux, so I can't help sorry.

Comment: In windows have u installed cygwin to use android ndk???

Comment: no I havent, I used cmd